# Construct tuple from dictionary values

Tags: python

Given a python a list of dictionary of key-value pairs i.e.

```
[{'color': 'red', 'value': 'high'}, {'color': 'yellow', 'value': 'low'}]
```

How to construct a list of tuples from the dictionary values only:

```
[('red', 'high'), ('yellow', 'low')]
```

Comment: `[tuple(d.values()) for d in data]` note order isn't guaranteed

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As simple as it gets:

```
result = [(d['color'], d['value']) for d in dictionarylist]
```

Answer (score 4):

If order is important then:

```
[tuple(d[k] for k in ['color', 'value']) for d in data]
```

Or:

```
[(d['color'], d['value']) for d in data]
```

Else without order guarantees or from an `OrderedDict` (or relying on Py3.6 `dict`):

```
[tuple(d.values()) for d in data]
```

Answer (score 0):

**For Dynamic List Of Dictionaries**

This is what I would go with in this case, I hope I have been of help.

```
tuple_list = []
for li_item in list_dict:
    for k, v in li_item.items():
        tuple_list.append((k,v))
```

Of course there is a one liner option like this one below:

```
tupples = [
    [(k,v) for k, v in li_item.items()][0:] for li_item in list_dict
]
```

Answer (score 0):

To generalize for any class instance where `self.__dict__` is defined, you can also use:

```
tuple([self.__dict__[_] for _,__ in self.__dict__.items()])
```

Answer (score -3):

```
a = [{'color': 'red', 'value': 'high'}, {'color': 'yellow', 'value': 'low'}]
b = [tuple(sub.values()) for sub in a]  # [('red', 'high'), ('yellow', 'low')]
```

Comment: Dictionary key order isn't guaranteed (yet), not even in Python 3.6.

Comment: @L3viathan OP did not specify that they have to be in order.